# Javascript! How do I choose a random array WITH a random array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Here's what I'm trying to do. I just got this random concoction to work after spending 3 hours at http://www.w3schools.com/js/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Loopin through an array using a for loop:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var myShows = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men',
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];

var show = myShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * myShows.length)];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = show




</script>
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
</body>
</html>
```

How could I make a random generator to randomly pull from two or more lists?
How would I make it do it on certain reuslts?

The outcome Im looking for:
Instead of 1 random result per click,

I click once, and it
1. runs through and array of "shows, cartoons, theatre"

If the result is shows, THEN RANDOMLY generate one of the show results
If the result is cartoons, Then Randomly generate a cartoon result
If the results is Theatre, Then Randomly Generate a theatre result

```
Shows = "bob newhard, mr.blevedere, growing pains"
cartoons = "chowder, flapjack, voltron"
Thearte = "Phantom of the opera, Lion king, Roots"
```

How would I do this Array, on an array?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

I would use a 2D array - this practically is an array, where each item is another array. You can have arrays with as many "dimensions" as you want, but here two is what we want.

So, your array would be:

```
var genres = [["bob newhard","mr.blevedere","growing pains"],["chowder","flapjack","voltron"],["Phantom of the opera","Lion king","Roots"]]
```

Now, I would randomly select a sub-array from `genres`. Lets do it like so:

```
var shows = genres[Math.floor(Math.random()*genres.length)]
```

Now, we just need to select a random item from **that** array. This is practically the same code, except we replace `genres` with `shows`:

```
var show = shows[Math.floor(Math.random()*shows.length)]
```

### Solution

(You'll need to click the button to generate a show the first time)

```js
function newshow() {
  var genres = [["bob newhard","mr.blevedere","growing pains"],["chowder","flapjack","voltron"],["Phantom of the opera","Lion king","Roots"]];
  var shows = genres[Math.floor(Math.random()*genres.length)];
  var show = shows[Math.floor(Math.random()*shows.length)];
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = show;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newshow()">New Show!</button><br>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing thank you! I didn't Know you could even do a genre! Ok well its back to the books for me! Can I ask you a question? How long did it take for you to learn this?

Comment: @Jfkg_JG_the_306 You're very welcome :D There are lots of topics in computer science, and to get to where I am now it's probably been maybe, 3 - 4 years? But, you definitely don't need to know all of that to make cool stuff, and you sort of learn as you go really. Also, the main difference between languages is syntax, so once you grasp the core concepts, then you can learn most languages with relative ease. The book I read when learning JS was http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027065.do, which was not only fun, but which also explained everything really :D

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you, could you click that little checkmark beside it? Thanks :D